Formatting, calculating, and Storing Currencies in Laravel 11
It seems like how currencies are displayed has evolved over the years.
I have found Number::currency() to be the most recent option, but doesn't account for the integer values from the database intending to be treated as /100;
100 -> $100 where the intended output is: $1.00
What is the modern way to store, compute (add/subtract), and display currencies in Laravel? I imagine I could do the first two (store, compute) as integers, but to display would need Number::currency($val/100), which feels kludgy.
I have also seen solutions that make use of packages (moneyphp/money for example), but would rather keep my implementation simple, and use a native solution.

Store as decimal(8,2)
Display and format with Number::currency()

Generally, it's not a good idea to store currency like this as it introduces error?

Not certain if you are asking or telling? What error does it introduce? Looking at a number of other question on SO, storing currency as decimal is the accepted format, as well as a number of other sources. You can always increase the number of decimals if you are needing a higher degree of accuracy if you are dealing with division of the currency.

Both? https://bornsql.ca/blog/how-should-i-store-currency-values-in-sql-server/
Also it seems like most libraries (including moneyphp, stripe API) take currency in integer form anyways

So there are several trains of thought on it. You can store currency with a larger decimal accuracy and not worry about calculating the cents to dollars, or store as INT and just do the math on the fly. Unless there are thousands of operations on a single page load or query, I am certain it wouldn't matter either way for performance.
It would just depend on what the needs of the application are. Do you need to have EXTREME precision, or is it okay to be off by $0.000001?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZjCQ3T5yXo :) I hear you though

It's never a good idea to store currency as floats.
